# <body onBlur = "self.focus();" does not let me type/edit the input text box in child window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an existing javascript code which does the following things

1. Open a popup window using window.open() which has a text field where user can input his/her value. This child window html is dynamically built by document.write.
2. Now an issue came that that whenever the child window opens in IE it gets minimized. Their requirement is that the child window should open as the top window.

Solution : I have made the child window open as top/front window by putting  body onBlur = "self.focus();"

But the problem is it does not let me edit the text box in the child window. 
I can not use jquery or any other library. I need a pure javascript code working in IE.

Comment: Sam Dufel rather than editing my question if you can help me out that will be appreciable

Comment: Please add the code that you've written so far - the popup html in particular